# Interactive Periodic Table

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation

I love Chemistry and the Periodic table is very useful for me, however I can't remember all of the properties of all of the elements, so I was wondering if there was some sort of Periodic table interactive app? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

The perfect app would be one that can give detailed information about a selected element, such as: atomic mass, atomic volume, atomic radius, lattice type, space group, electron configuration, melting point, boiling point, heat of fusion, series, group, period, block, and maybe even some historical information such as date of discovery, and the appearance of the element.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Gelemental` is just the app for you! Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gelemental
```

It shows all the information you requested and so much more! Take Cadmium for instance:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is symbolic colour?

Comment: @Holloway: In the first image of the full periodic table you will see that they are grouped by different colours, the symbolic colour is which colour it is on the table, for instance Cadmium is a sort of light red colour (or `#ffd88e`).

Comment: Ok, so it's specific to this program?

Comment: Also just noticed this is a self answered question. Are you connected to the program at all? If so, Cadmium is the wrong colour in the example you've given.

Comment: @Holloway: Yes, that's why it is in the `Miscellaneous` section. Though I think that in most programs they use similar colour coding.

Comment: @Holloway: No, I have no connection with the program, but as it is open-source I could try and fix that.

Comment: @Holloway: Wait, I think that as each element has a different colour, it is a little confusing but I think that each element has its own associated colour that is different from the group which it is colour coded into. If you get the program you will see what I mean.

Comment: Great program, thanks for pointing it out. Not a criticism, because it's still very useful, but I find running this on Mint means there are no colours (it's all white/grey/blacks). I will install it onto one of my Ubuntu VM's where, I guess, I will see the colours.

Comment: @glaucon: Well, Mint isn't Ubuntu, nor is it supported here, but if it was I would have made sure that the application worked on it, all I can say is that it will work on all official Ubuntu flavours and Ubuntu itself, but I can't say for anything else.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda - hah ! Sorry I forgot which forum I was on - that is I forgot I was on the Ubuntu forums ! I take your point .

Comment: @glaucon: Also, SE sites are not *forums,* they are *Q&A* sites. **;P**

Comment: for some unknown reason the colours don't appear on my OS - 20.04.02 LTS, 64-bit, GNOME 3.36.8. Any help is welcome as this program is so cool!

Answer (score 1):

I use a graphing calculator called `qalculator`. It has a periodic table from which you can copy and paste.

```
sudo apt-get install qalculator
```